# MySQL connection The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012

I have an ASP.Net app which in one page is opening a connection to MySQL database on port 33060 to a remote Win 10 PC.

The application is running fine to my PC, but when i've upload to the server which is Windows Server 2012 then i get the error "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm" when trying to read data from the database.

The port 33060 is available and the user has the right to read the data.

The app is running fine to every pc but not in Windows 2012 which is the production server on Internet.

The code for the connection to the MySQL database is below

```
Dim oConn = New MySqlConnection("server=win10pc;User Id=user;password=pass;database=database;CharSet=utf8;Convert Zero Datetime=True ;port=33060;")
```

I tryied everything i found about the error in this site but with no luck.
The target framework is 4.6 and i have SSL on the server Windows 2012 but not on Win 10 who host the MySQL because is a home PC.

Answer (score 1):

The default MySQL Port Number is **3306** NOT 33060 are you sure you are having the correct port number in you connection string?

Comment: Yes i've changed for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

My server Windows 2012 have TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2

I installed the TLS 1.0 and now can communicate succesfully with the other Windows PC.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What version of .net your app is running? What version of .net is installed on the server?
What version and edition is your MySQL server?

I can think of this base on little information you are giving, perhaps you can check in this direction:

```
".NET 4.5.1 is no longer supported. End of support 2016. TLS 1.2 was added in .NET 4.5.2

In order to use TLS 1.2 you'll have to upgrade your projects to the minimum supported .NET version."
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As I said the target framework is 4.6 and the server version is 4.7. The Mysql server is 8. The strange thing is that I can connect from any other app from server except the IIS.

Comment: server=win10pc; is this your server host name or your developer's pc name in your connection string?